# Differences between using "used to" and the simple past

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, past-tense

In following examples I understand:

1. Situations are in the past.
2. Situations are continued until some time and stopped.
3. Situations are regular, routine and repetitive.

My question is should we use **used to** or simply use the simple past of a verb? When and how do we use **used to** and what are the differences?

Please, explain this to me with examples.

**E.g. 1**

> I used to prepare this report when I was in Company X.
>
> I prepared this report on daily basis when I was in Company X.

**E.g. 2**

> I used to work for this company.
>
> I worked for this company for 8 years.

**E.g. 3**

> He used to play for X Country.
>
> He played for X Country.

**E.g. 4**

> He came to meet me regularly.
>
> He used to come to meet me regularly.

Comment: Do the answers to this question help: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27587/whats-the-difference-between-used-to-like-and-liked/27594#27594

Comment: [Please don't use `code formatting` for quotes or emphasis.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/28/6407) It is ugly and difficult to read. Use *italics* for single words or phrases, and blockquote (put > at the start of the line) for complete sentences or paragraphs.